# Haskell - counting number of recursions

Tags: haskell

I have a simple function that calculates the n-th fibonnaci number below:

```
fibonacci :: Integer -> Integer
fibonacci 0 = 0
fibonacci 1 = 1
fibonacci n = (fibonacci (n-1) ) + (fibonacci (n-2))
```

But i am interested in a way to count the number of recursions of this function. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
recursions :: Integer -> Integer
recursions 0 = 0
recursions 1 = 0
recursions n = recursions (n-1) + recursions (n-2) + 2
```

For the base cases, there are no recursions, for everything else, we have two direct recursive calls and those that are invoked from the two.

You can also re-use the `fibonacci` code,

```
recursions n = 2*fibonacci (n+1) - 2
```

Answer (score 7):

This puts one in mind of `sigfpe`'s [illustration of the so-called Writer monad](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html). You might do it a bit more systematically like this:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Writer
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.Monoid

fibwriter :: Int -> Writer (Sum Int) Integer
fibwriter 0 = return 0
fibwriter 1 = return 1
fibwriter n =  do a <- fibwriter (n-1)
                  b <- fibwriter (n-2)
                  tell (Sum (2::Int))
                  return (a + b)
```

Used thus:

```
*Fib> runWriter $ fibwriter  11
(89,Sum {getSum = 286})
```

This is the same definition, but with the 'side effect' of logging each additional pair of recursions.  We can also add a side effect in `IO` if we want to see all the crazy recalculation involved in the 'naive' definition while it  happens:

```
fibprint :: Int -> WriterT (Sum Int) IO Integer
fibprint 0 = return 0
fibprint 1 = return 1
fibprint n = do  a <- fibprint (n-1)
                 record a
                 b <- fibprint (n-2)
                 record b
                 return (a + b)
 where  record x = lift (putStr $  ' ' : show x) >> tell (Sum 1)
```

For fibonacci 11 this gives us this absurdly repetitious show, as the calculation climbs toward 89:

```
*Fib> runWriterT $ fibprint 11
 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0
 1 1 2 5 13 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8 21 1 0 1 1
 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5
 13 34 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1
 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 13 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8 21 55
 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0
 1 1 2 5 13 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8 21 1 0 1 1
 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 8 1 0 1 1 2 1 0 1 3 1 0 1 1 2 5
 13 34(89,Sum {getSum = 286})
```

Comment: there is no `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer`, but `Control.Monad.Writer`

Comment: It's in the `transformers` package, `Control.Monad.Writer` is in `mtl`